# Differences between jQuery .on() data argument and using javascript bind()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events

In response to [jQuery .on() method - passing argument to event handler function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15904243/814206) two approaches are suggested:

### Using javascript [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

In a comment on the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15904292/814206) [Ignatio Segura](https://stackoverflow.com/users/381914/ignacio-segura) suggests using [javascript `bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

> Actually, there is a neater syntax for that, using JS bind(): $(document).on('dblclick', '#an_tnam tr', ADS.bind(null, 'hello')); First parameter is the value you want "this" to have inside callback function.
>   *— [Ignacio Segura](https://stackoverflow.com/users/381914/ignacio-segura) Feb 19 2016 at 16:24*

### Using the data parameter in jQuery's [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

David Barker's answer suggests using the `data` argument of jQuery's [`.on()`-method](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$(document).on('dblclick', '#an_tnam tr', { extra : 'random string' }, function(event)
{
    var data = event.data;

    // Prints 'random string' to the console
    console.log(data.extra);
});
```

which the handler can access via `[event.data][6]` (as shown in the annoymous handler above).

---

### Question

What are the differences between [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) an the `data` parameter to jQuery [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)?

When should I use which?

Answer (score 0):

### Differences:

- [jQuery `on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) supplies the element from which the event originated as `this`.

  With Javascript [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) `this` is set at bind time; it does not point to the element that triggered the event unless you explicitly set it to that element (e.g. via `handler.bind($(elementSelector)[0], boundValue, ...)`.
- Javascript `bind()` creates a new bound function (an "[exotic function object](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-bound-function-exotic-objects)" (see [§ Description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Description) in [bind() API-documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)).

  The documentation for jQuery `on()` does not specify whether `on()` creates any object.
- Javascript `bind()` follows a more functional style of programming (i.e. using partial applied functions).

  The setting of a property in the `event` structure as done by jQuery's `.on()` is used in many different programming styles and not signature any programming paradigm in specific.
- Javascript `bind()` forces a specific order of parameters —which might go against what you would consider logical for the handler—; i.e.:

  `function handler(boundParameter_1, ..., boundParameter_n, event) {
     ...
  }`

  [This JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kaspervandenberg/mh8tuh25/) demonstrates how the bound function (e.g. `bf` and `bf2` in the example) forwards any additional parameters to the original function (e.g. `f` in the example).  The [altered fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kaspervandenberg/k0ap485w/) demonstrates how this works for an event handler bound via jQuery's `on()`.

  Passing extra data via jQuery's `on()` 'hides' the data as a property of [`event`](http://api.jquery.com/event.data/)
- **If** the handler ignores the event-object and **if** one wants to call the handler without an event, the handler to which extra data is bound via javascript's `bind()` is easy to call both with its arguments (partially) bound via the via bound function and with different values for the bound argument as a regular function; e.g.:

  `var boundHandler = handler.bind(null, "Bound value 1", ..., "Bound value n");
  // Call without event:
  boundHandler();

  // Call with different values:
  handler("Other value 1", ..., "Final other value");`

### Similarities

- Programmatically triggering (see [jQuery trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) and an [example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kaspervandenberg/th475pnn/)) both the event with bound function and the event with extra data passed via `on()` passes the data to the handler.

### Conclusion

- With `bind()` the value of `this` is not set to the element that triggered the event.  If you rely on `this` being that element, then use jQuery's [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
- If you value consistency and your code uses jQuery's `on()` with passing extra data, then always use [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for passing extra data.

  The same holds for using [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) when the restof your code always uses `bind()`.
- If you and your colleagues value clean functional style for javascript code, then use javascript's [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).
- If you want to avoid jQuery specific functionality as much as possible (e.g. for reasons of portability), then use javascript's [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).