# Javascript convert anonymous function to named function passing clicked object

Tags: javascript, jquery, anonymous-function

I've got a piece of code that looks like this and works as expected

```
const $tableID = $('#edit_history_table');

$tableID.on('click', '.table-save', function() {
    var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr");

    var key = currentRow.find("td:eq(0)").text(); // get current row 1st TD value

    ...
});
```

If you click on the save icon in a table it gets that rows data.
Now for integration in other parts I need to convert it to a named function so that (for example) a 'save all' button can just loop through the records and save each one of them.

I was expecting something like this to do the trick (where you pass the row as the parameter so you can use the function in the fore-mentioned use case)

```
$tableID.on('click', '.table-save', save_row($(this).closest("tr")));

function save_row(currentRow) {
    alert(currentRow);

    var key = currentRow.find("td:eq(0)").text(); // get current row 1st TD value

    ...
}
```

But when launching the page, I immediately see the alert box. And when clicking the button nothing happens.

I honestly don't really have a clue how to do it in another way...

No anonymous function can be used like in [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15904243/jquery-on-method-passing-argument-to-event-handler-function).

Comment: Have `save_row` return a function which has the code you want to use inside it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery .on() method - passing argument to event handler function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15904243/jquery-on-method-passing-argument-to-event-handler-function) (Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15904419/8398549) answer)

Comment: that's because you directly call the function, doing this :  `save_row($(this).closest("tr"))`

Comment: @Cid Not really. This again focusses on anonymous functions. (Or maybe I just don't understand it as I'm not a JS programmer).

Comment: @evolutionbox then how do you pass a parameter to it?

Comment: You invoke the `save_row` function immediately and set its *response* as the event handler. This is why it runs on page load. To fix this either wrap the `save_row()` call in another anonymous event handler (which would be redundant given your goal) or pass the *reference* of the function to the event handler and use the `this` reference within the function: `.on('click', '.table-save', save_row);`

Comment: @S.J. `saveData = function (myParam) { return function (event) {` - If you don't like anonymous functions, why not give them a name?

Comment: @S.J. I insist, read the second answer, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15904419/8398549) `$tableID.on('click', '.table-save', { currentRow: $(this).closest("tr") }, save_row);`. And then, your function : `function save_row(event) { console.log(event.currentRow); }`

Comment: @Cid that's what I tried now (almost had it except the `event.` but the result is still undefined. I even tried `event.data.currentRow` but then I get an object that doesn't appear to contain my row fields.