# Should I convert primitive to object if I want to access its (object's) properties lots of times?

Tags: javascript, performance, object, primitive

For example, suppose I have a long string primitive called `str`. I know I can use `str.substr` because the browser, behind the scenes,

1. Converts `str` into a string wrapper object, equivalent to using `new String(str)`
2. Calls the `substr` method with the correct parameters on the `String` object returned by step 1
3. Disposes of the `String` object
4. Returns the string (primitive) from step 2.

(https://stackoverflow.com/a/9110389/1529630)

But what happens if I want to use `str.substr` lots of times? For example

```
var positions = [1, 5, 8, 9, 15, ...],    //long array
    substrings = new Array(positions.length);

for ( var i = positions.length - 1;  i >= 0;  --i ) {
    substrings[i] = str.substr(positions[i], 2);
}
```

Should I convert `str` to an object before that loop in order to avoid creating and destroying an object at every step?

Comment: [Actually, using the primitive is faster in Chrome](http://jsperf.com/string-primitives-versus-objects).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a blog entry dedicated to that question [here](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/12/performance-with-javascript-string-objects/).

In short, working with primitive values is faster **most of the time** because of optimizations made by most JS engines. However, that might not be the case when accessing non-native members on primitives.

For instance, we can read in the article that:

> In the SpiderMonkey JS engine, for example, the pseudo-code that deals
>   with the “get property” operation looks something like the following:

```
  // direct check for the "length" property
  if (typeof(value) == "string" && property == "length") {
    return StringLength(value);
  }
  // generalized code form for properties
  object = ToObject(value);
  return InternalGetProperty(object, property);
```

> Thus, when you request a property on a string primitive, and the
>   property name is “length”, the engine immediately just returns its
>   length, avoiding the full property lookup as well as the temporary
>   wrapper object creation.

Here's the conclusion:

> Based on the benchmarks described above, we have seen a number of ways
>   about how subtle differences in our string declarations can produce a
>   series of different performance results. It is recommended that you
>   continue to declare your string variables as you normally do, unless
>   there is a very specific reason for you to create instances of the
>   String Object. Also, note that a browser’s overall performance,
>   particularly when dealing with the DOM, is not only based on the
>   page’s JS performance; there is a lot more in a browser than its JS
>   engine.