# What type of object is a Javascript prototype?

Tags: javascript, prototype

```
function Person(name) {
  this.name = name;
}
var rob = new Person('Rob');
```

- Person is a function.
- Person is an object.
- Person is not a Person.
- rob is an object.
- rob's prototype (`__proto__`) is Person.prototype, so rob is a Person.

But

```
console.log(Person.prototype);
```

outputs

```
Person {}
```

Is Person.prototype an object? Array? A Person?

If it is an Object, does that prototype also have a prototype?

**Update on what I have learned from this question (Friday 24 January 2014, 11:38:26 AM)**

```
function Person(name) {
  this.name = name;
}
var rob = new Person('Rob');

// Person.prototype references the object that will be the actual prototype (x.__proto__)
// for any object created using "x = new Person()". The same goes for Object. This is what
// Person and Object's prototype looks like.
console.log(Person.prototype); // Person {}
console.log(Object.prototype); // Object {}
console.log(rob.__proto__); // Person {}
console.log(rob.__proto__.__proto__); // Object {}

console.log(typeof rob); // object
console.log(rob instanceof Person); // true, because rob.__proto__ == Person.prototype
console.log(rob instanceof Object); // true, because rob.__proto__.__proto__ == Object.prototype

console.log(typeof rob.__proto__); // object
console.log(rob.__proto__ instanceof Person); // false
console.log(rob.__proto__ instanceof Object); // true, because rob.__proto__.__proto__ == Object.prototype
```

- Prototypes are just plain objects.
- typeof is useful to determine if something is object or primitive (and what sort of primitive it is), but useless to determine what sort of object it is.
- **LHS instanceof RHS** returns true if RHS.prototype turns up somewhere in the prototype chain of LHS.

Comment: i guess everything is an object in JS...!

Comment: @Sudhir: `42` <---- this is not an object, but a number literal

Comment: @zerkms true, missed the word "almost" in it.. :)

Comment: `Person.prototype` is an object that inherits from `Object.prototype`. ... `Person.prototype instanceof Object; // true` ... `Person.prototype.__proto__ === Object.prototype; // true`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is Person.prototype an object?

Yes. Everything <sub><sup>(interesting)</sup></sub> is an object :-) See [How is almost everything in Javascript an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9110389/1048572) for details.

> An Array?

No, definitively not.

> A Person?

Depends. Most people would say it's not an instance of `Person` - it's the essence of all Persons (their prototype :-). However, `console.log` seems to identify it as such because it has a `.constructor` property pointing to the `Person` constructor.

> If it is an Object, does that prototype also have a prototype?

Yes. Every Object does have a prototype. These build the so-called *prototype chain*, at whose end is a `null` reference. In your particular example, it's

```
      rob
       |
       v
 Person.prototype
       |
       v
 Object.prototype
       |
       v
      null
```

Comment: I really like both answers - thanks @Sandu too. Both made me think this through and I appreciate that. This answer is my preferred though - the visual representation of the chain helped a lot!

Answer (score -1):

```
typeof Person === "function"
typeof Person.prototype === "object"
```

Comment: `typeof null === "object"` `typeof window === "object"` You've not really begun to answer the questions being asked.

Comment: OK, this is something interesting. Applying this to my simple code, `(typeof rob === "Person")` is **false**, so functions don't actually define new types? `rob` is just an object whose prototype (`__proto__`) is `Person.prototype`?

Comment: @Robert Mark Bram: `(rob instanceof Person)`. "so functions don't actually define new types" --- nope

Comment: -1. You have successfully confused the OP :-) @Robert: No new `typeof`-types (there's only `object` and `function` for non-primitive types anyway) are introduced, yes. They might introduce `instanceof`-"type hierarchies" by their prototype chains, yes, but the things using prototype chains are still ordinary objects.

Comment: OK, I think I have a better understanding now. Javascript "typeof" types are just object, function and the primitives (undefined, null, number, string, boolean). However, instanceof will return true if RHS appears in LHS's prototype chain - and this shows that rob is Person and an Object, while Person is a Function and Object, and Person.prototype is an Object.

Comment: @Robert: Yes. Only that someone messed up the `typeof` operator and `typeof null == "object"` for some reason :-/