# Type of prototypes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, prototype, instanceof, typeof

What's the type of prototypes in Javascript?

I mean for example the type of:

- Object.prototype
- Boolean.prototype
- Number.prototype
- String.prototype
- Date.prototype
- RegExp.prototype
- Array.prototype
- Set.prototype
- Map.prototype
- Function.prototype

When using typeof all of them return "object", but I was wondering if they are instances of a particular type of Object.

Comment: Umm, yes. `Boolean.prototype` is a type of object that is a boolean prototype. `Number.prototype` is similarly a type of object that is a number prototype. And so on. They are all instances of a particular type of object, each of them being themselves.

Comment: How about this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21299416/what-type-of-object-is-a-javascript-prototype

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "particular type of object"? `Array.prototype` actually is an array (exotic object), and `Function.prototype` is actually callable, but besides that, objects in JavaScript are just defined by their prototype chain - try to follow that for the objects you listed.

Comment: What I mean by "particular type of object" is some object that retrieves "true" when used with "instanceof".

Comment: They are all instances of `Object`. But other than that, there isn't a `Prototype` object that is on the prototype chain of any prototype.