# Why typeof + is not "function" javascript

Tags: javascript, function, typeof

As in the title, why

```
typeof +
```

doesn't give "function"?

Comment: ... because `+` is an operator?

Comment: Why it should be function?

Comment: What's JavaScript? JavaScript is not C++ :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`+` is an [operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators), it's not a function. `typeof +` is therefore a syntax error.

Comment: While this answer is perfect, it does lead to another question:  Wouldn't it be nice if `+` **were** a function... `var total = list.reduce(+, 0)`.  Or even nicer, if we had automatic currying/partial application and we defined `reduce = function(fn, start, list)` so that we could just do `sum = reduce(+, 0)`.  No, that's just **[crazy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming)** **[talk](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Haskell)**!

Comment: yep, after playing with haskell and scheme, since javacript was presented to me as kinda similar to them, I was hoping for it. Apparently I was mislead.

Comment: @user1544128, JavaScript has many things in common with lisp languages, but this is not one of them.

Comment: @ScottSauyet, you can easily make a `var sum = function(a, b) { return a + b; }` function and use it the same way you would use `+` if it were a function.

Comment: @rid: Yes, I understand.  I've been working on **[Ramda](https://github.com/Crosseye/ramda)**, a functional programming library for JS to give me some of these capabilities I'd like to have.    So I know that I can create them if I like.  And my versions of `foldl`/`foldr`/`reduce` are automatically curried, and I do have an `add` function, and `sum` is defined in terms of `reduce` and `add`.  But there's a big part of me that would love it if this were in the language instead...

Answer (score 2):

`typeof` only returns types of objects ([pretty much everything in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108925/how-is-almost-everything-in-javascript-an-object)) and primitives.

See the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) for `typeof`.

As rid points out, `+` is an operator and not an object or primitive.