# Why does reading a property sometimes throw an error in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have some variables:

```
var s = 's', i = 0, o = {}, a = [], n = null, nan = NaN, u;
```

**How can I make any sense of when reading `x.p` will return undefined, and when it will throw a `TypeError`?**

```
s.p;  // undefined
i.p;  // undefined
o.p;  // undefined
a.p;  // undefined
n.p;  // TypeError!
nan.p;  // undefined
u.p;  // TypeError!
```

P.S. Are `null` and `undefined` the only weird values in this way? Are there others?

**Edit**

I'm aware that by declaring variables as I have, several of my values have been automatically wrapped by objects (e.g. `Number`), despite being primitives. Therefore I can treat them like "proper" objects (e.g. `{}`, `[]`) and attempt to read their properties. But I can't find much explaining what is and isn't wrapped this way.

Comment: Well one is  undefined and one is trying to access a property of system that is not an object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, `null` and `undefined` are the only values that throw an exception when being used in a property access. The dot and bracket [property accessors](http://es5.github.io/#x11.2.1) do invoke the internal [CheckObjectCoercible function](http://es5.github.io/#x9.10), which is defined as following:

> The abstract operation `CheckObjectCoercible` throws an error if its
>   argument is a value that **cannot be converted to an Object** using
>   [`ToObject`](http://es5.github.io/#x9.9). It is defined by Table 15:
>
> ```
> Table 15 — CheckObjectCoercible Results
> Argument Type | Result
> --------------+------------------
> Undefined     | Throw a TypeError exception.
> Null          | Throw a TypeError exception.
> Boolean       | Return
> Number        | Return
> String        | Return
> Object        | Return
> ```

`null` and `undefined` being the values that represent Nothing cannot be converted to objects ("wrapped" as you say). Notice that you could of course have an object with an existing property that throws on access, like

```
var o = {get p() { throw new TypeError("you may not access this"); }};
o.p // TypeError
```

Answer (score 1):

When you're reading the property of something that's undefined. You're basing saying:

What is undefined of undefined? or in the case of null what is undefined of null ? Neither undefined nor null are objects, therefore you can't set or get properties on/from them. With that in mind, an error will be thrown.

Comment: Why is `NaN` an object, then?

Comment: @Blackhole `NaN` is not an object, it's a numeric constant. When you try to use it as an object, it's automatically promoted to a Number instance just like any other number.

Answer (score 1):

When the object is null/undefined, it'll throw an error because **it'll try to access a property of an object that does not exist in first place**.

On the other cases, it'll try to access a property of an existing object and will return undefined because the property is not found.

Please note that almost everything in js is an object, as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108925/how-is-almost-everything-in-javascript-an-object).

Comment: The most voted answers says the opposite. The String, Number, Null and Undefined variables in the question are primitives, not objects.

Comment: "An object in JS is simply a hashmap with key-value pairs." Even though it's primitive, it does behave like an object, since you can access properties and methods of said string, int and so on

Answer (score 1):

let's firstly start with

why undefined on:

```
 var s='s';
```

You assigned s to string which is primitive type. Javascript is tricky here in one sense. Though primitive type, when you try to access the property by doing:

```
    s.p
```

It firstly does this internally:

```
    String(s)
```

and creates the object and then tries to see if it has that property which is, of course not defined and thus you get undefined. Almost similar things happen with numerical assignment and NAN.

For `n=null:`

If you do:

```
 var n=null;
 typeof n;//"object"
 n.p// throws typeerror
```

In fact,null can be thought of special kind of object without any properties or method to represent absence of value and thus, you get typeerror when you try to access any properties of null.

```
a.p
o.p
```

Easily, you can see that you are trying to access the property of an object than is not defined or not built-in and thus it should say, undefined. You should be surprised to see other than that :D.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the other answers here, there is an easy way to check if a property access will throw an exception. Simply loosely compare the value you're unsure of to `null`, like so:

```
if(x != null) { // note the LOOSE equality, rather than !==
    // do something with x.prop
}
```

The reason this works is that only `null` and `undefined` * throw errors on property access, and they are only loosely equal to each other. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_when_to_use_them.

* There is also a case where some JS objects can apparently "emulate" being undefined, in which case they also are loosely equal to `null` and `undefined`.