# What does assigning to {}.toString mean?

Tags: javascript, function, tostring

I'm learning JavaScript and I came across this snippet, which demonstrates type detection:

```
var toClass = {}.toString // Copy a reference to toString for objects into toClass variable

alert( toClass.call( [1,2] ) ) // [object Array]
alert( toClass.call( new Date ) ) // [object Date]
```

I don't understand what the empty curly brackets are for in the first line, so I remove them like this:

```
var toClass = toString
```

And the code still works. 
But in the following code,

```
function getAge () {
    alert(this.age);
}

var p1 = {
    age:1
};

var tellAge=getAge;
tellAge.call(p1); //1
```

if I change `var tellAge=getAge` to `var tellAge={}.getAge`, I get an error: cannot read property "call" of undefined.
Why is this? Is it because `toString` is a built-in function?

Comment: Check my answer below for a line per line overview of what your code is doing and how it works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is it because toString is a built-in function

Not exactly, it is because both `Object` and `window` in javascript both have a `toString` method.

---

The `{}` in `{}.toString` represents a new object in javascript. Object has a `toString` method and that is what you're creating a reference to.

If you omit the `{}` it is equivalent of `window.toString` and as luck would have it the `window` object itself has a `toString` method. So everything continues to work.

When you do `{}.getAge` you're telling the interpreter to get the `getAge` method from Object, which does not exist, setting `tellAge` equal to `undefined`, which leads to the error `cannot read property "call" of undefined`

Comment: This is probably the cleanest answer I've ever read in my entire life - just wow! And may I add that everything in JS is an object?

Comment: @SidneyLiebrand thank you, that's a nice compliment.

Comment: and a well deserved one to be honest, it's so simple that it hurts my brain thinking about how effective it is lol :P

Comment: @Jamiec: thanks! and may I ask is there a difference between the two `toString` methods? I tried `toString.call(p1)` and `p1.toString()`, both give me `[object Object]`

Comment: @YiboYang - they are NOT the same method (demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kk8c83cp/) but they probably do something pretty similar under the hood. Its down to the implementation of the javascript engine in the browser/host

Comment: @YiboYang : Check my answer below for a `line per line` overview of what this code is doing and exactly how it works.

Comment: @canon alright, not **[everything](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108925/how-is-almost-everything-in-javascript-an-object)**

Answer (score 1):

- `{}` returns a new object of type `Object` [***(1)***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object).
- `toString()` returns a string representing an object [***(2)***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString).
- For an object of type `Object`, `toString()` should return the value `[object Object]`.
- `call()` executes a method with a given `this` value and arguments provided individually [***(3)***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).
- Any function that is not explicitly assigned as a method to an object is implicitly assigned to the `Window` object. Using `this` in such a function always refers to the `Window` object.

Now, let's get back to your code, shall we?!

```
var toClass = {}.toString
```

This first creates a generic object of type `Object`. It then returns the method `toString` (the method itself, not the return value.

That means that toClass is a now a function. It uses the object `{}` as a `this` value. So if you just run `toClass()`, you should always get the value `[object Object]`.

Now, here comes the tricky bit!

Take this command :

```
toClass.call( [1,2] )
```

What happens here? Well, this is similar to calling `toClass()`, except that your `this` value is no longer `{}`. Instead, it is replaced by `[1,2]` [***(4)***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). That's why you get `[object Array]` as a result!

Now take this command :

```
toClass.call( new Date )
```

What happens here? Well, the same thing, really. This is similar to calling `toClass()` or `toClass.call( [1,2] )`, except that your `this` value is replaced by an object of type `Date` [***(5)***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). That's why you get `[object Date]` as a result!

Now, take this function :

```
function getAge () {
    alert(this.age);
}
```

What happens here? Well, this function just alerts the property `age` of the `this` value in your method. By default, this property is unknown because the `this` value is `Window` and the `Window` object has no `age` property.

Now, take this command :

```
var p1 = {
    age:1
};
```

Here, you create an object that has exactly one property. That property is `age` and has the value 1.

Now, take this command :

```
var tellAge=getAge;
```

Here, you assign the function `getAge` to the variable `tellAge`. By default, both functions use the same `this` value, which is the `Window` object.

```
tellAge.call(p1);
```

What happens here? Well, it's pretty much the same as calling `tellAge()` or `getAge()`, except that your `this` value is no longer `Window`. Instead, it is replaced by `p1`. You get `1` as a result, because object `p1` has a property `age` and that property has a value of 1!

Now, let's examine the following command :

```
var tellAge={}.getAge
```

Why does this generate an error? What you're trying to do here, is creating a generic object of type `Object`. While it has a `toSting` method by default (which is defined in its prototype [***(6)***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype)), it does not come with a `getAge` method. That's why you're getting an error.

Now take the following code :

```
var p2 = {
    age : 18
};

var p3 = {
    age : 25
};

var FObject = {
    getage : function() {
        return this.age;
    }
};

var tellAge = FObject.getage;
alert( tellAge.call(p2) ); //18
alert( tellAge.call(p3) ); //25
```

So what does this do? Well :

- First you create an object named `p2`, which has an `age` property with value 18.
- Then, you create an object named `p3`, which has an `age` property with value 25.
- Then, you create another object object named `FObject`, which has an `getage` method.
- Then, you assign the method `FObject.getage` to the variable `tellAge`.
- Then, you call `tellAge.call(p2)`. This is similar to calling `tellAge()`, except that your `this` value is replaced by the object `p2`. That's why you get `18` as a result!
- Finally, you call `tellAge.call(p3)`. This is similar to calling `tellAge()` or `tellAge.call(p2)`, except that your `this` value is replaced by the object `p3`. That's why you get `25` as a result!

I believe this last example gives a good overview of the behavior you're looking into.

---

**References :**

1. [***Object***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)
2. [***Object.prototype.toString()***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString)
3. [***Function.prototype.call()***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)
4. [***Array***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)
5. [***Date***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)
6. [***Object.prototype***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype)

Comment: While all true, Im not sure which part of the question this is answering.

Comment: @Jamiec : I added a lot of additional information, which gives a line per line overview of what the code is doing and how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Oh my... that's a lot of things to answer in such a short time... But you have a long way to go in JavaScript, but you're gonna love it...

1) Object notation. You should google for JSON.

Object notation means, you can define data using a specific format, relevant to JavaScript.

> { }   in object notation means, an object... more specifically speaking, this is already an instance of an object.

You could also write this in plain javascript, it would look like this:

```
new Object()
```

2) Functions are first class citizens.

Well, functions are indeed a highly valuable asset in the JS ecosystem. That means you can do basically anything you imagine with them. This includes, copying a reference to a function that "belongs" to another object.

> {}.toString   is a function.  You would normally invoke it by doing {}.toString( )
>
> You are instead, just copying the reference to the function in a variable. In this case you "store" the function in the variable "toClass"

3) Prototype chain. You should google, well, prototype chain haha.

Prototype chain, for putting things simple is "like" class inheritance. So that means if a class A has a method "blah" and class B is a "child" class of A, this, well, will also have the method "blah".

> In JS world, the top of the prototype chain is "Object". And many functions are already defined in the **prototype** of Object.  Including "toString"

4) General Relativity Problem... a.k.a. this, call, and apply.

As Functions are first class citizens, they basically can exist without even belonging to a specific object instance.

> That means, you can choose on which **this** context you want the function to be invoked on.

By default, when you invoke a functions that seems "attached" to an object, that object becomes the **this** context of that function call:

```
{}.toString()    // This executes toString in the context of {}
```

But as I said, you can just choose where the function is actually executing. For that the methods "call" and "apply" exist.

Our previous example can be translated into:

```
Object.prototype.toString.call({})  // This executes toString in the context of {}
```

5) Global objects in your environment.

This is not easy topic, because now JavaScript runs not only on the browser but also on the server... NodeJS is a good example of that.

Assuming you're running this in a browser... there is a global object called **window**

You can basically call any function in your global object.

> So toString  is equivalent to  **window**.toString and window is descendent of Object, it will also get the method from the Object.prototype.

**Now your answer**

> **getAge** is not defined in Object.prototype, so you cannot invoke a non existing function.

Comment: Your formatting is weird, half of your description is in block quotes when you're not quoting anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Just made this example to make it clear to you. [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2km6of74/)

```
var toClass = {}.toString; // type detection

function person(age){
    this.age = age;
    this.getAgePlusOne = function(){
        return this.age + 1;
    };
}

var you = new person(20); // create a new person object and set age propery to 20
console.log(you);
var yourAge = you.getAgePlusOne(); // call created person object's function getAgePlusOne() to retrieve value
console.log(yourAge);

console.log(toClass.call(you)); // object
console.log(toClass.call(you.getAgePlusOne)); //function
```