# A function and an object at the same time?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible that after creating a function variable you can actually assign properties to it as if it's a regular object? This is what I did:

```
var example = function(a, b){
    console.log(a, b);
}
example.someProperty = 'hi there';
```

Then I typed these lines in the browser console:

```
example('Hello', 'world') // Hello world
example.someProperty // hi there
```

So now basically the 'example' var acts as a function and as an object at the same time. This raised some questions for me, one of which is why, and another one - is there a way to do this by creating an object literal, because I can't think of such way.

Comment: In javascript, functions are objects.

Comment: **First Class Objects**

Comment: Your question regarding object literal isn't clear.

Comment: Have you tried your code before asking? It works fine just as you assume.

Comment: Thank you all. I do realize of course that functions in javascript are objects. I also know they have prototypes, but I didn't figure out the connection, to be honest. Now it seems so obvious to me and I feel stupid.

Comment: Related: [How is almost everything in Javascript an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9108925/4642212).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> So now basically the 'example' var acts as a function and as an object at the same time.

It doesn't *act as* a function and an object, it **is** a function and an object. Functions are objects in JavaScript.

> This raised some questions for me, one of which is why

Fundamentally because that's what Eich decided to do in those 10 days in May 1995. Why he decided that is something only he can answer, but there have been many languages through the years that also see no reason to treat functions as something special and different. Presumably he was influenced by those. It's incredibly handy and flexible that functions are proper objects. For instance:

```
function foo() {
    // ...
}
var f = foo;
```

I can use the variable `f` to refer to `foo` because `foo` is an object. In many languages, such as Java, it's a real pain to do that (though Java is a bit better now thanks to its recently-added lambdas).

Since functions are objects, they have a prototype, which means I can add features to *all* functions. For instance: I find it quite handy to be able to take a function and "bake in" (or "[curry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying)") arguments:

```
// A simple function
function foo(a, b) {
    console.log("a is " + a);
    console.log("b is " + b);
}

// Create a new one that, when called, will call the original passing in
// 1 as the first argument and then passing in any further arguments,
// preserving the `this` it was called with
var f = foo.curry(1);

// Call it
f(2); // "a is 1" / "b is 2"
```

Since JavaScript doesn't have a `curry` function (it has `bind`, which is similar, but interferes with `this`), I can add one:

```
var slice = Array.prototype.slice;
Object.defineProperty(Function.prototype, "curry", {
    value: function() {
        var f = this;
        var args = slice.call(arguments);
        return function() {
            return f.apply(this, args.concat(slice.call(arguments)));
        };
    }
});
```

And voilà, now I can use `curry` on any function:

```js
var slice = Array.prototype.slice;
Object.defineProperty(Function.prototype, "curry", {
  value: function() {
    var f = this;
    var args = slice.call(arguments);
    return function() {
      return f.apply(this, args.concat(slice.call(arguments)));
    };
  }
});

// A simple function
function foo(a, b) {
  snippet.log("a is " + a);
  snippet.log("b is " + b);
}

// Create a new one that, when called, will call the original passing in
// 1 as the first argument and then passing in any further arguments,
// preserving the `this` it was called with
var f = foo.curry(1);

// Call it
f(2); // "a is 1" / "b is 2"
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="//tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

> is there a way to do this by creating an object literal

No, the only way to create a function is to start out with a function. You can't take a non-function object and turn it into a function.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation.

Answer (score 4):

Functions are indeed objects in JavaScript. As any other object, they also have a prototype, that's where methods such as `.call()`, `.apply()` & `.bind()` come from.