# Chaining async functions in bluebird with ".then". What is the best way?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bluebird

I am currently learning about bluebird and came up with this bit of code (Using Express.js and Mongoose) to test it out:

```
let startServer = Promise.promisify(app.listen, app);
let connectDB =  Promise.promisify(mongoose.connect, mongoose);

startServer(3000)
  .then(() => connectDB(MongoURI))
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log('Exception ' + e);
  });
```

The function in my first .then call is only returning another function.
Therefore I was wondering, if there is a way to pass connectDB directly to .then and make it work. Something like this:

```
startServer(3000)
  .then(connectDB, MongoURI)
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log('Exception ' + e);
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Therefore I was wondering, if there is a way to pass connectDB directly to .then and make it work.

Yes, that's possible via something called *currying* (after Haskell Curry, the mathematician). You'll also see it called *partial application*. Basically, you create a new function that, when called, will call the original with the arguments you specify when creating it.

JavaScript has [`Function#bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) which does two things: 1. Sets what `this` will be, and 2. Does currying. It doesn't look like your example cares what `this` will be, so we can use it for this.

Ex:

```
startServer(3000)
  .then(connectDB.bind(null, MongoURI))
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log('Exception ' + e);
  });
```

The `null` is for the `thisArg` argument, which we're effectively not using.

Here's a simpler example, just to illustrate:

```js
function foo(a, b) {
  snippet.log("a = " + a);
  snippet.log("b = " + b);
}

// "Curry" 1 as the first arg
var f1 = foo.bind(null, 1);

// Call the resulting function:
f1(2); // "a = 1, b = 2"
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="//tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Whether it's *desireable* is another question (and probably an opinion-based one). Your original with the arrow function is nice and clear and not likely to be expensive (in terms of memory or time). But it is *possible* to do ths, yes.

---

If you wanted the function to receive the `this` it was called with (probably not in your case, but it's fairly common in, say, jQuery event handlers in browser-based JavaScript), it's also easy to write a function that just does the currying without the `this` stuff `Function#bind` does. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33098092/157247) has a very simple, un-optimized example.