# javascript adding property to function

Tags: javascript, function

Let us say we have a function.

```
function Rabbit(){
  console.log("shiv");
}
```

Now without creating an object of this function i can assign the property of this object

```
Rabbit.bark = function(line) {
 console.log("name is", line);
};
```

What does this mean. do this add a variable bark to function. or does this add a property to `Rabbit` object, even if I am not creating an object using the `new` operator.

Comment: functions are objects, `bark` is a property of an object. `bark` is not a traditional method however, but if you added `new` and `prototype` into the mix, then `bark` would be a method of instances. as-is, there's no connection from `.bark` to any instance if you simply added `new` to the code above, but you can reach `bark` as a static method, like `Array.isArray()`

Comment: think of a function as an object, something _like_ `{name: "Rabbit", length: 0, body: "code here", arguments: [], this: {}, _closures: {}, call: function call()... }` you can add new properties yourself if you'd like.

Comment: so can i say that when i call function e.g console.log(rabbit()) i am calling some specific property of that object

Comment: yeah, _basically_ the function's `.call()` method is how you invoke it. close enough. to be nerdy, there are internal hidden properties inside functions you can read about in the spec that you are actually calling/using, not a userland endpoint (instance method)

Comment: Hi @shivgarg, if you think my answer helped, you can mark it as the accepted answer which helps others to quickly find it. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A function and an object at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33097986/a-function-and-an-object-at-the-same-time)

Comment: yes, it does answer my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Function** in JavaScript is just an object, it is called [Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) object.

And just like any other types of object, it has its own constructor (`new Function(...)`), methods (`apply`, `bind`, `call`...) and properties (`arguments`, `caller`, `name`...) . [See the document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function).

You might be familiar with creating a function like this:

```
function Rabbit() {
    console.log('shiv');
}
```

Then you should know that you can also create a function like this:

```
var Rabbit = new Function('console.log("shiv")');
```

Now, you might guess it out. If you add a new property to a Function object, as long as you **don't overwrite** the existing one, the function is still working just fine.

> do this add a variable bark to function

- No, the function has it own closure, the only way to add variable to the function is to bind it to `this` object using `Rabbit.bind(object)`

> do this added a property to Rabbit object

- Well, since the "Rabbit object" is just an object, Yes.

Comment: I don't see the purpose of showing the `new Function` case.

Comment: @torazaburo just try to emphasize that `Rabbit` is just an object created by `new Function`.

Comment: I edited the example to make it more semantic related to the question.

Comment: if i create a instance of Rabbit, i am not able to access the property "bark". whats the issue..can someone explain?               


function Rabbit(){
  console.log("shiv");
}
Rabbit.bark = function(line) {
 console.log("name is", line);
};
var m = new Rabbit();

m.bark("test");

VM135:1 Uncaught TypeError: m.bark is not a function
    at <anonymous>:1:3

Answer (score 3):

> what does this mean. do this add a variable bark to function. or do
>   this added a property to Rabbit object

*do this add a variable bark to function* - **No**

*or do this added a property to Rabbit object* - **Yes**

bark is a property of object of type [Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)

> even if i am not creating an object using new operator

Rabit is already an object (of type [Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)). You are not creating an instance of this object, just that you are adding a property to it.