# Why is it possible to add a property to a function?

Tags: javascript, function

I created a function called `add`.

```js
function add(a,b){
  return a + b;
}

add.val = 10;
console.log(add) // => function add()
console.log(add.val) // => 10
```

I’d like to know how and why it is possible to create the `val` property on `add`. Why do we only see the output as *function* when `add` also has `val` on it?

Comment: Duplicate of [A function and an object at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33097986/4642212).

Comment: Everything in js are objects, even a function. You just adding a new property `val` to the object `add`

Comment: _“And why we only see output as function when add also has val on it.”_ — What do you mean? `console.log(add)` shows something like _function add()_ just fine without the additional property.

Comment: And speaking of _“internals”_ — Internally, a function is just an object with a _\[\[Call\]\]_ internal slot. If you want to learn more about internals, read the [specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#function-object).

Comment: Related: [How is almost everything in Javascript an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9108925/4642212).