# Does a function's name act as a variable?

Tags: javascript, function, javascript-function-declaration

I have a question about this code below:

```
function myfunc () {
return 2 + 2;
}

console.log(myfunc);
```

Does anyone know why, when we log 'myfunc' to the console, we get the entire function itself back? Or in other words, is 'myfunc' acting as a variable that holds the function's contents, or is it just referencing that function?

Because if I go ahead & add this to the code...

```
myfunc = undefined; //or any other value like myfunc = 20;
```

...then since myfunc's value is changed, I can no longer use it to invoke the function. So what is 'myfunc' really?

Comment: This question has been asked before I believe.

Comment: It is actually variable with constructor `Function()`

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir can you show me where?

Comment: Please refer this [link](http://ryanchristiani.com/functions-as-first-class-citizens-in-javascript/)

Comment: @Bail3y I'm looking for it right now.

Comment: you are printing the whole function to just print the return you would do console.log(myfunc()) thats why you are getting the whole block and not just the return

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why base a javascript namespace as a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33677338/why-base-a-javascript-namespace-as-a-function)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40675821/javascript-variable-name-same-with-function-name/40675938#40675938

Comment: Given that functions are objects in JS, there's not really a difference between "*holding the function's contents, or just referencing that function*"

Answer (score 2):

The answer is **yes**, a function declaration creates a symbol in the local function scope (or global scope if the declaration is in that context) that works exactly like a variable declared with `var` (though function declarations are hoisted above `var` declarations).

Now, a function *expression* like this:

```
var x = function helloWorld() { return "hello world"; };
```

does *not* create a local "helloWorld" symbol [(except when it does)](https://kangax.github.io/nfe/#named-expr). The value of a function expression is a reference to the created function, and that can be assigned to a variable just like any other value.

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question. So would you say a function declaration is also, in a way, an expression? Since the function's name resolves to the function?

Comment: No. A function declaration statement is **not** an expression. When the `function` keyword is the first token in a statement, it's a function declaration, and the main effect that has on coding is that the function cannot be immediately invoked.

Comment: Ok that definitely makes sense now. I just don't get 1 thing, sorry. If a function declaration creates a symbol that works exactly like a variable...then aren't we saying the functions name resolves to the function itself? If we are, then doesn't that mean we have an 'expression' where the name evaluates the function? I know you just said no, but I just don't get the reasoning. If we have a variable that evaluates to the number 1, that's an expression, yet if we have a function declaration that has a name, who evaluates to the function, it's not an expression? What am I missing...

Comment: Functions are objects, and in JavaScript the "value" of an object is a *reference* to the object. So the value of a function name in its declaration context is a reference to the function object that the declaration created. It can be assigned to other variables or object properties or passed as an argument to a function. The function declaration is not an expression in the same way that a `var` declaration is not an expression: it simply *isn't* according to the rules of the language. The declaration *creates* a new symbol and gives it a value, but it's not itself an expression.

Comment: Note that the term "expression" has a precise definition; it's not just a colloquial term. It's a specific part of the language syntax.

Comment: To put it another way: asking "Is a function declaration statement an expression?" is like asking "Is a function declaration a `while` loop?". It just isn't.

Comment: Interesting I understand 100% now, thanks again Pointy! But when you said a var declaration is not an expression, that confused me. Declaring var x = 2 + 2; is not an expression?

Comment: No. `2 + 2` is an **expression**, `var x = 2 + 2;` is a **statement**. If you want a crystal clear explanation, read *JavaScript: The Definitive Guide* by **David Flanagan**.