# A Function that can be an Object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I mean I tried to make a function that can have a function has a property, but a Function is not an Object ? So I am confused, I would like to resolve this :

```
var destroy = require('alphaDestroyerBeeBop');

const penny = destroy(); // this explodes the computer
const tissue = destroy.graphicCard(); // this Just explodes the graphic card
```

`destroy()` is a function but `destroy` in `destroy.graphicCard()` looks like an object. Like an hybrid object.

Is there a way to do that in JavaScript ?

Comment: yup. `function foo () {}; foo.bar = 5;` bar could just as well be a function

Comment: _"but a Function is not an Object"_ - It is -> [oop - How is almost everything in Javascript an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108925/how-is-almost-everything-in-javascript-an-object#9110389)