# How to assign a Function to a Function using TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Please consider my previous post [A Function that can be an Object in JavaScript ? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49643274/a-function-that-can-be-an-object-in-typescript?noredirect=1#comment86294230_49643274) which was marked as duplicate and it makes perfect sense. I was asking how I could resolve that :

```
function foo () {}
foo.bar = function () {}
```

because during testing this didn't work, but while it would make pure sense in commonJS, my issue is TypeScript specific. If I write the snippet above in my editor and try to compile, Typescript will tell :

> Property 'bar' does not exist on type '() => void'.

How should I write to give a function property a function ?

Comment: You have some options [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766528/build-a-function-object-with-properties-in-typescript). Check answers below the accepted one

Comment: check this out - https://www.reddit.com/r/typescript/comments/6cljb3/is_it_possible_to_add_methods_to_functions_in/