# How to parse the following json and take individual string from that

Tags: java, android, parsing

I was trying to parse the following `JSON` but unfortunately there is no key for the array and the array is inside another array 
How to parse the below `JSON` that consist of an array inside another array without key name? 
I was trying to parse the following `JSON` but unfortunately ther is no key for the array and the array is inside another array 
How to parse the below json that consist of an array inside another array without key name?

```
    [
        [{
            "logid": "12345",
            "assignees": "",
            "creator": "XYZ",
            "activity": "asdsadsad",
            "contentid": "sadsadasd",
            "createuser": "dasd",
            "crtdate": "asdasdsadsad"
        }],
        [{
            "logid": "sadsaddasd",
            "assignees": "",
            "creator": "sadasdsad",
            "activity": "sdfsdfsdfsdf",
            "contentid": "dsfsdfdsfsd",
            "createuser": "sfsdfdsfs",
            "crtdate": "dfsdfdsfdsf"
        }],
        [{
            "logid": "sdfsdfsdfdsf",
            "assignees": "",
            "creator": "dsfsdfsdfds",
            "activity": "dsfdsfsdfdsf",
            "contentid": "4sdfsdf",
            "createuser": "sdfdsfsdf",
            "crtdate": "dsfsdfsdfsdf"
        }],
        [{
                "logid": "sdfsdfsdf",
                "assignees": "",
                "creator": "fsdfsf",
                "activity": "sdfsdfsdf",
                "contentid": "dfsdf",
                "createuser": "dsffdsf",
                "crtdate": "sdfdsfsdf"
            },
            {
                "logid": "dfsdfsdf",
                "assignees": "",
                "creator": "dsfsdfsdf",
                "activity": "dfsdfsdf",
                "content": "sdfsdfsdf",
                "contentid": "2dfsdfsdfsdf",
                "email": "sdfsdfsdf",
                "img_name": "dsfsfsdf",
                "createuser": "sdfsdfsdf",
                "crtdate": "dsfsdfsdf"
            },
            {
                "logid": "sdfsdfsdf",
                "assignees": "",
                "creator": "Nsdfsfsdfsdf",
                "activity": "dfsdfsdf",
                "content": "fdsfsdfsdf",
                "contentid": "dsfsdfdsf",
                "email": "sdfsdfsdf",
                "img_name": "sdfsdfsdf",
                "createuser": "1fdsfsdfsdf",
                "crtdate": "dfsdfsdf"
            },
            {
                "logid": "dsfsdfdsf",
                "assignees": "",
                "creator": "dfsdfsd",
                "activity": "fsdfsf",
                "contentid": "dsfsdfsdfsd",
                "createuser": "1dsfdsfdsf",
                "crtdate": "dsfsdfsdf"
            },
            {
                "logid": "last",
                "assignees": "",
                "creator": "sdfsdfsdfsdfsd",
                "activity": "dsfsdfsdfsdf",
                "contentid": "dsfsdfsdfs",
                "createuser": "dfsdfsdfsdf",
                "crtdate": "sdfsdfdsfsdfsdfsdf"
            }
        ]
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to get elements using a key only. You have an array and data should be extracted like:

```
myArray[0][0].logid
```

or

```
myArray[0][0]['logid']
```

Also, in javascript, [everything is an object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9108925/5051731).