# Is `Object` a function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, prototype

Consider this function:

```
function Foo(){
    var a = "3";
};
```

According to *[__proto__ VS. prototype in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959727/proto-vs-prototype-in-javascript)*,

```
Foo.__proto__ = Function.prototype
Function.prototype.__proto__ = Object.prototype
```

I understood that part, but if I do this in the Google Chrome console:

```
Object.__proto__
output: ƒ () { /* native code */ }

Function.__proto__
output: ƒ () { /* native code */ }
```

**Q1:** Why are they pointing to Function? What actually are `Function` and `Object` and how are they different from each other, because **`Object` is actually a function**?:

```
typeof Object
"function"
```

**Q2:** If everything is an object in JavaScript, then why is `Object` a function? Also, how is a function actually implemented inside JavaScript? What happens to the variables declared inside a function? Is a function converted into an object by the JavaScript compiler?

Sorry if I am missing something obvious. I am really confused by the way function and object are implemented in JavaScript.

Comment: *"typeof Object"* Of course, it is a function because this is constructor function. Even `Number`, or `Boolean` are functions.

Comment: Do note that there is a difference between "object" (the concept) and the function "Object". In JavaScript, all functions are objects, including "Object". On the other hand not all objects are functions (eg. `var a = {}`)

Comment: You are doing exactly that, though: `Object.__proto__` => You get the property `__proto__` from `Object`, which is a `function` and thus an `object`.

Comment: You perfectly well can do eg. `Foo.a = 5`. But be aware that this is independent of the variables you declare *inside* the function. The contents of the function are just a block of code that you associate with the function, its scope is *not* the "object" part that you are referring to.

Comment: i just checked in chrome console, we can't do that, it will just create a new object Foo and add a new property "a" to it. the original function will remain unchanged. if we could do that, then we should just be able to print the value by console.log(Foo.a), but that doesn't work

Comment: You've messed up something in your tests. It's perfectly legit and working to add a property to a function. For example, jQuery's `$` is a function, but you can call some methods of it, like `$.each()`.

Comment: okay, after you add a property, how do check if the property is inside the function, consider this function: foo(){var a =1}. now can i access a like foo.a ?

Comment: See a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oy7kmwf8/). In your example in the comment, you can't access _a local variable_ outside of the function, but when creating _a property_ to the function, it's accessable both inside and outside of the function.

Comment: please see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rs2y1qg9/.

Comment: Please don't mess local variables with function properties, they are not the same.

Comment: The (almost) only difference between a regular object and a function is, that a function object has the internal [[callable]] flag set.

Comment: @Teemu okay, i get it now, thanks

Comment: Just to make it sure, see [another fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oy7kmwf8/1/) = ).

Comment: @Teemu just one more question , consider this fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/rs2y1qg9/2/
why doesn't the this keyword work inside when i call the function?i understand that `this` must point to an object, but if the function is an object, then the context should be set for this

Comment: In a traditional function call `this` refers to the object before the method name, i.e. when calling `object.Foo();`, `this` in `Foo` method refers to `object`. When you just call `Foo();` you're not defining the context.

Comment: I recommend this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/24811539/277304

Comment: @leonbloy That answer (talking about "units") is rubbish. Did you link the right one?

Comment: This sounds very much like a duplicate of https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/369631/unable-to-solve-mystery-of-functions-in-javascript/369666#369666

Comment: You've asked a half dozen questions here.  **Please try to focus only on one question at a time**.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You seem to be confused between "object" (the data structure) and `Object` (the function).

An object is a concept in JavaScript that is a generic container for some data. An object contains properties with keys and associated values.

In JavaScript, everything that is not a [primitive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive) is an object. This includes functions, which are basically a special type of object that can be "called" with the `()` syntax.

JavaScript provides a number of built-in functions that have various purposes. Two such functions happen to be called `Object` and `Function`. So in other words `Object` is a function and thus also an "object" (data structure).

Let's take your function `Foo` as an example:

```
function Foo() {
    var a = "3";
}
```

`Foo` is a function. This means that `Foo` can be called, eg. `var f = Foo()`. In this case `f` will be `undefined` since `Foo` doesn't return anything.

Because `Foo` is a function, it is also an object. This means we can also add and read properties from it:

```
Foo.bar = 5;
Foo.bar++;
console.log(Foo.bar); // prints 6
```

Please note that this "object" part of `Foo` is not related to the contents of the function. That means that the code you declared (`var a = "3"`) is irrelevant. You cannot access `var a` in any way here because it does not exist until you call the function. If you were to do `Foo.a`, you are *not* manipulating `var a` inside the function; you are working with the property `a` on the object `Foo`.

You can however do it the other way around and access properties on `Foo` inside of the function:

```
function Foo() {
    var a = "3"; // a is local to this scope, you cannot get to it from outside
    console.log(a); // prints 3 - local variable a is accessible inside the scope of this function
    console.log(Foo.a); // prints 5 - a is a property on object Foo, and is accessible here
}
// var a inside Foo cannot be accessed here
Foo.a = 5;
Foo();
```

Edit: Re. your question regarding "this" in the comments. `this` is a special keyword in JavaScript that refers to an object. However, this object is *not* the function itself, it is a new object that is created when you call a function using the `new` keyword:

```
function Bar() {
    this.a = 10;
    console.log(this == Bar); // prints false
}
var bar = new Bar();
console.log(bar.a); // prints 10
```

A function that is meant to be called with the `new` keyword is referred to as a "constructor function". `Object` and `Function` are both examples of constructor functions, which is why their names start with an uppercase letter (a convention in JavaScript).

When you create an object with a constructor function, the property `prototype` of this function is used as the prototype (accessible through `__proto__`) of the created object.

```
console.log(bar.constructor == Bar) // prints true
console.log(bar.__proto__ == Bar.prototype) // prints true
```

`this` is also used for other things, but that is a broad subject and way out of scope for this question.

Comment: @TiiJ7 i have one small doubt though, if i do `typeof(Function.prototype)`, 
output: "function". is it just referring to Function.prototype.constructor?

Comment: @vikrant `prototype` is just a property of the function `Function`. And apparently it was defined as a function itself. Objects can have functions in their properties, and since `Function` is a function (and thus an object), it works for that too. I don't know why they decided to make `Function.prototype` also a function, but it doesn't really matter since a function can do anything an object can.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i did check the ECMAScript spec, they have mentioned a reason regarding this as "
The Function prototype object is specified to be a function object to ensure compatibility with ECMAScript code that was created prior to the ECMAScript 2015 specification."
https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-function-instances-prototype

Answer (score 18):

Function and Object are both constructor functions which can be used to create a function and an object, respectively, which is the reason `typeof Function` returns `function`.

About how functions and objects are related in javascript, consider the following points:

1. All non-primitive types are objects in JavaScript.
2. All objects directly or indirectly inherit from Object.prototype (unless prototype is changed explicitly using setPrototypeOf).
3. All native functions inherit from Function.prototype which inherits from Object.prototype, so it means function indirectly inherits from Object.prototype because functions are treated as objects in JavaScript.
4. The reason functions are treated as objects is because they can be passed as parameters to other functions and can be returned from functions i.e. higher order functions(a powerful feature of javascript).
5. A function can be called using the `()` operator because the JavaScript engine knows it is declared using a function keyword and has executable code. So whenever it is called, the JavaScript engine creates a new execution context and set the `this` binding and then executes the function. None of that happens when you try to call an object instead an error is thrown i.e. "is not a function".

   So we can say that not every object is a function because they may have not been declared using the function keyword and not have executable code.
6. As the function is treated as an object in JavaScript, we can add properties to it, create new objects from it.
7. A non-function type object cannot be called using `()` because it does not have executable code and is not declared using the function keyword. Instead, it is declared using `new Object()` or object notation and contains methods and properties.

I hope it clears both questions.

Comment: No. Not all objects inherit from `Object.prototype`, not all functions inherit from `Function.prototype`. Functions are callable because that's their intrinsic feature (what makes these objects functions), not because they inherit from `Function.prototype`. Similarly, objects can have properties because that's what defines an object, not because they inherit from `Object.prototype`. The inheritance chain (whose mere *existence* is another feature of being an object) only influences which inherited properties/methods are accessible, but does not otherwise affect the kind of value.

Comment: @Bergi What functions do not inherit from Function.prptotype? Also i said "A function can be called using () operator because javascript engine knows it is declared using a function keyword and it inherits from Function.prototype and have executable code" not only because it inherits from Function.prototype.

Comment: `var f = Object.setPrototypeOf(function() {…}, null); f()` for example. Yes, you didn't say "only because", but you said "because" - and the inheritance is not related at all to whether it can be called. "has executable code" is the only criterion.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for the explanation. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 16):

**Q1: Why are they pointing to Function?**

A1: Because they are functions. `Function` and `Object` are just constructor functions.

function is a `Function object`. object is an `Object object`.

**Q2: If everything is an object in JavaScript, then why is `Object` a function?**

A2: Because `Object` is just a constructor function.

```js
typeof Object
// 'function'
typeof new Object()
// 'object'
```

And a function is an instance of `Function`, so that makes a function an object.

```js
(function(){}) instanceof Function
// true
```

Comment: "And a function is a instance of Function, so that makes a function object." why does that make a function object?

Comment: What I was trying to say is just, *`Function` constructs an object which is function*.

Comment: if it is a function, why is it called object?

Comment: because it's *an object of `Function`*. difference between `Function` and `function` is a point.

Answer (score 11):

Fundamentally

`Functions` has some code that can be executed. 
`Object` are those which contains data.

For class `Point` having `x` and `y`.

```
class Point {
    constructor(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    isOrigin() { return x == 0 && y == 0; }
}
let p = new Point();
```

**Answer 1**

In this, `p` is `object` which contains data or other functions.

`p.isOrigin` is function.

Similarly, class `Point` is itself a `function` which when **runs** produces `p`. That's why all classes like `Object` and `Functions` are `functions` more precisely `constructor functions`.

**Answer 2**

> If everything is an object in JavaScript, then why is `Object` a function?

Same as Answer 1.

> Also, how is a function actually implemented inside JavaScript?

Different JavaScript engines will have different implementations. They have specifications which they need to follow.

> What happens to the variables declared inside a function?

Off topic. Every `function` runs with a scope which holds all data for that functions.

> Is a function converted into an object by the JavaScript compiler?

Not sure what are you asking.

Comment: Close this question if answered. Ask another question. `this` keyword itself is a huge topic. 
https://medium.com/quick-code/understanding-the-this-keyword-in-javascript-cb76d4c7c5e8

Answer (score 6):

The ECMAScript reference is very nice for answering such questions.

- https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-language-types is the entry point about what types the language supports, and it introduces the concept that everything there is is either a rather standard value (boolean, string etc.), or an object. But no further types.
- https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-object-type explains the Object Type. At heart, it's a collection of attributes and/or accessors (think getter/setter). This also introduces the term "function object".
- https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots shows the internal semantics, internal methods etc. of objects. At the end of that section, specifically, the "function object" specific internals ("Call" and "Construct") are described, including little details like the constructor being optional.

Hence, to answer your question: `Foo` can be nothing but an object (because everything else on the menu is a basic value type). Hence, `Foo()` is a special syntax which simply invokes the internal `Call` method of that object. But `Foo` itself is an object through and through, you can do with it everything else you can do with any other object, including setting arbitrary attributes on it.

Having a method defined on an object simply means that there is an attribute with that name, and the attribute references an object, which happens to be a "function object".

Something which can be used as a constructor is, again, simply an object which happens to have a `Construct` internal method, and the syntactic sugar to call it.

As you know, there are no classes in JavaScript, it's a prototype-based object-oriented language (it's as *object*-oriented as you can get, it literally has nothing else). So any kind of "prototype" is just a link between objects. A constructor method (as explained in the link given above) simply calls the constructor method with the object on which it was called (i.e., something like `String`) as an argument, just like the language would call `Call` with `this` being the object the method has been invoked on.

Answer (score 5):

`Object` is the ***constructor function*** of all objects. So, `typeof Object==="function"`

Here is a snippet for visualisation:

```js
console.log(typeof Object)            //function (which is an object)
var object=new Object()               //An instance of Object 'class'
console.log(typeof object)            //object
console.log(object instanceof Object) //true, because object is created by Object()
```

`Function` is the ***constructor function*** of all functions (including itself...)

So, although **not everything is a function**, but most of the Uppercase native identifiers refer to a constructor function.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, **Object** is of type function. It is a class/Function implementation which when invoked with new (`new Object()`) will result in an object with allocated memory.