# Is a variable an Object in JS

Tags: javascript, object, var

I'm currently learning JS, and while working on my project, I was wondering if a variable is by definition an object, or a kind of object, or nothing a all.

I know we can create objects through var, but I'm not sure if a var is always an object.

Thanks for the answers !

Comment: object is a type and any variable can be any type.

Comment: A "variable" is only a *name*.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108925/how-is-almost-everything-in-javascript-an-object

Comment: `var x=6;` here x is an int, not an object; `var x={z:6};` here x is an object

Comment: @mplungjan no, it's a number.

Comment: Okay ! Thank you very much for your answers !
I see what I missed in my reflexion, so thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables are not classified as objects. They are their own classification as a storage address. Now as Nina said in the comment, objects are types which are in the same category as: `array`, `string`, `number`, and `boolean`. A variable can hold any of these types and be referenced to in your code.

Answer (score 0):

A variable is rather like a *bucket*, where different values can be put in. An object is such a value.

> I know we can create objects through var

Not really. With the `var` keyword you can declare a  variable (a bucket), to create an object you could use an object literal.

Answer (score 0):

Think of `var` as a mechanism to create a memorable handle for your primitive and reference values like your object. The `var` keyword itself doesn't do anything other than [declare a handle in a scope and allow you to initialize](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) the handle to the value you desire.