# javascript confusing variable syntax

Tags: javascript

I am new to JS, and JS syntax is definitely confusing to me as I'm used to other languages instead.

```
const x = 5;
x.yy = 3;
console.log(x.yy); // undefined
```

How is `x.yy = 3;` a valid syntax?

and why is `x.yy` undefined when `x.yy =3;` took in place?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9110389/5648954) from one of the dupes above, that explains your situation, just with a string (rather than an number)

Comment: On a side note . Try reading "Javascript the good parts" book