# Extra Object in prototype chain of Number object

Tags: javascript, prototype

```
var i = 0;
i.__proto__
```

Why do I see extra Object in prototype chain for Number object?

When I try to check `i.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__` is `null` but devtools screenshot below its of type Object.

[image]

Comment: It gets wrapped in an object because you tried to access a property of it, and `Number.prototoype` inherits from `Object.prototype`

Comment: It's called a **wrapper type**.

Comment: @CertainPerformance could you please tell me more on this or share some resources to go through.

Comment: @connexo could you please tell me more on this or share some resources to go through.

Comment: Did you read the linked canonical, which goes into great detail?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108925/how-is-almost-everything-in-javascript-an-object.
I am not getting "It gets wrapped in an object because you tried to access a property of it".
When I try to check i.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__ is null but dev tools screenshot shows its of type Object.

Comment: No, `i.__proto__.__proto__ === Object.prototype`, so its own prototype should really be `null`. Your screenshot is looking at the `prototype` property, not the `__proto__` property

Comment: @CertainPerformance Right, that is also my understadning. Is there issue with chrome devtools? Why is displaying `prototype` of `Object` instead of `null` when I click on `(...)` to expand `__proto__` of `Object`. Or I am missing something?

Comment: @JavaDeveloper I guess it evaluates the `__proto__` getter on the originally logged value, i.e. `Number.prototype`, and you get `Object.prototype`. Notice it has a `get __proto__: (...)` again, it'll be the same there. In conclusion: don't use the deprecated `__proto__` getter for anything, just look at the `[[Prototype]]` in the devtools and use `Object.getPrototypeOf` to access it in code.

Comment: @Bergi Yes looks like that. I observed same thing in other objects also. Thanks.