# how array can be object and array at the same time?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

**code:-**

```
let a = [1,2,3,4,5]
console.log(a)
console.log("type of a:-",typeof(a))
console.log("isArray a:-",Array.isArray(a))
```

**note:-** i ran it on chrome
**output:-**
(5) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
type of a:- object
isArray a:- true

i was checking Array is object or just array but it is showing it is array and object at the same time

Comment: Because an array of s a special type of an object in JavaScript

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108925/how-is-almost-everything-in-javascript-an-object

Comment: See [JavaScript Prototype Chain (1 minute coding)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bsEIwvXoBxE).

Comment: How can a tomato be red and round at the same time?